# $r=3 i \cos (t \omega )+4 j \cos (t \omega )+5 k \sin (t \omega )$ Speed

Tags: vectors

Vector Valued Function

Ive been aksed to find the velocity, speed and acceleration and describe the motion of a particle whose position at time t is:

$$r=3 i \cos (t \omega )+4 j \cos (t \omega )+5 k \sin (t \omega )$$

$$\frac{dr}{dt}=-3 i \omega  \sin (t \omega )-4 j \omega  \sin (t \omega )+5 k \omega  \cos (t \omega )$$

My problem is that the speed is given as the absolute value of the velocity, but I am not able to see that the speed is 5[Omega]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what you get

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dr}{dt}&=-3i\omega\sin(t\omega)-4j\omega\sin(t\omega)+5k\omega\cos(t\omega)\\
\left|\frac{dr}{dt}\right|^2&=\frac{dr}{dt}\cdot\frac{dr}{dt}\\
&=\left[-3i\omega\sin(t\omega)-4j\omega\sin(t\omega)+5k\omega\cos(t\omega)\right]\cdot\left[-3i\omega\sin(t\omega)-4j\omega\sin(t\omega)+5k\omega\cos(t\omega)\right]\\
&=9\omega^2\sin^2(t\omega)+16\omega^2\sin^2(t\omega)+25\omega^2\cos^2(t\omega)\\
&=25\omega^2\cos^2(t\omega)+25\omega^2\sin^2(t\omega)\\
&=25\omega^2[\cos^2(t\omega)+\sin^2(t\omega)]\\
&=25\omega^2\\
\left|\frac{dr}{dt}\right|&=5|\omega|
\end{align}$$